# Как улучшить код на Си(длинная арифметика)?

Tags: c, строки, инспекция-кода

Задача:

> Главный вождь племени Абба не умеет считать. В обмен на одну из его земель вождь другого племени предложил ему выбрать одну из трех куч с золотыми монетами. Но вождю племени Абба хочется получить наибольшее количество золотых монет. Помогите вождю сделать правильный выбор!

```
INPUT.TXT
```

> В первой строке входного файла INPUT.TXT записаны три натуральных числа через пробел. Каждое из чисел не превышает 10<sup>100</sup>. Числа записаны без ведущих нулей.

```
OUTPUT.TXT
```

> В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT нужно вывести одно целое число — максимальное количество монет, которые может взять вождь.

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 103
char* maxNum(char *n1, char *n2);
int length(char s[]);
int main()
{
    FILE *in;
    FILE *out;
    int i,j;
    char c;
    char num1[N];
    char num2[N];
    char num3[N];
    char *nums[3] = {num1,num2,num3}; 
    in = fopen("input.txt","r");
    for (i=0;i<3; ++i){
        j = 0;
        while(c=fgetc(in)){
            if ( c == '\n' || c == ' ' ){
                (*(nums+i))[j] = '\0';
                break;
            }           
            (*(nums+i))[j] = c;
            j++;
            
        }
    }
    fclose(in);
    out = fopen("output.txt","w");
    fprintf(out, "%s",maxNum(*nums, maxNum(*(nums+1),*(nums+2))));
    fclose(out);
    //printf("%s", maxNum(*nums, maxNum(*(nums+1),*(nums+2))));
    return 0;
}

int length(char s[]){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<N,s[i]!='\0';i++)
        ;
    return i;
}

char* maxNum(char *n1, char *n2)
{
    int i;
    if (length(n1)>length(n2))
        return n1;
    if (length(n2)>length(n1))
        return n2;
    for (i=0; i<N;i++){
        if (n1[i]>n2[i])
            return n1;
        if (n2[i]>n1[i])
            return n2;
    }

}
```

Можно ли в maxNum использовать `n1>n2 ? n1 : n2` ?
Код работает, но как сделать код меньше, "красивше". Может я где-то не правильно типы данных использовал (код работает). Где еще можно указатели можно использовать? Может вообще другой алгоритм использовать? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Так какой это язык? С или С++? Если С++, то упростить можно ооочень сильно.

Comment: А не проще через `string`, с дописыванием ведущих нулей?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat C

Comment: @Harry в C есть string? (Моя вина, что оставил тег 'C++' в вопросе)

Comment: Написал и на том, и на другом...

Comment: Не понял. Откуда в этой задаче взялась "длинная арифметика"? "Каждое из чисел не превышает 10100".

Comment: 10^100 > 2^64-1     (^ - степень)

Comment: @Aminev Timur: Ну так значит так и напишите в вопросе! У вас в вопросе нет никакого "^".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой набросок на C++:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ifstream in("INPUT.TXT");
    string s[3], t[3];
    in >> s[0] >> s[1] >> s[2];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        t[i] = string(102-s[i].length(),'0') + s[i];
    }
    int r = (t[0] > t[1]) ? 0 : 1;
    r = (t[r] > t[2]) ? r : 2;
    ofstream out("OUTPUT.TXT");
    out << s[r] << endl;
}
```

То же самое на C:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    FILE * in = fopen("INPUT.TXT","rt");
    char s[3][102];
    char t[3][102];
    fscanf(in,"%s %s %s",s[0],s[1],s[2]);
    fclose(in);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        memset(t[i],'0',101-strlen(s[i]));
        strcpy(t[i]+101-strlen(s[i]),s[i]);
    }
    int r = (strcmp(t[0],t[1])>0) ? 0 : 1;
    r = (strcmp(t[r],t[2]) > 0) ? r : 2;
    FILE * out = fopen("OUTPUT.TXT","wt");
    fprintf(out,"%s\n",s[r]);
    fclose(out);
}
```

Comment: Каков алгоритм?

Comment: Я же писал - *А не проще через `string`, с дописыванием ведущих нулей?*